# Scrollview not working with React Navigation Top Tabs

Tags: javascript, react-native, scrollview, react-native-scrollview

I have this code below:

```
<ScrollView
  style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: defaultStyles.colors.lighterGray }}
  contentContainerStyle={{ flexGrow: 1 }}
>
  <ImageBackground
    style={styles.coverPhoto}
    source={{ uri: image }}
    resizeMode="cover"
  >
    <ReviewBadge rating={rating} />
  </ImageBackground>
  <SupplierHeader name={name} price={price} category={category} />
  <View>
    <SupplierTabs />
  </View>
</ScrollView>
```

It basically has a header image, which is the `ImageBackground` and `SupplierHeader` , below that is a component called `SupplierTabs` which contains the code below...

```
const Tab = createMaterialTopTabNavigator();

const SupplierTabs = () => {
  return (
    <Tab.Navigator
      screenOptions={{
        tabBarLabelStyle: styles.tabBarLabelStyle,
        tabBarIndicatorStyle: styles.tabBarIndicatorStyle,
        tabBarStyle: styles.tabBarStyle,
      }}
    >
      <Tab.Screen
        name="SupplierOverviewTab"
        options={{
          tabBarLabel: "Overview",
        }}
        component={SupplierOverviewTab}
      />
      <Tab.Screen
        name="SupplierReviewsTab"
        options={{
          tabBarLabel: "Reviews",
        }}
        component={SupplierReviewsTab}
      />
      <Tab.Screen
        name="SupplierGalleryTab"
        options={{
          tabBarLabel: "Gallery",
        }}
        component={SupplierGalleryTab}
      />
    </Tab.Navigator>
  );
};
```

However, the `Scrollview` does not work (it does not scroll) unless I declared a fixed height for the `View` that's wrapping the `SupplierTabs` element (like `height: 9999`) which I can't do because the content is going to be dynamic.